# How to add a middleware to catch all success requests on express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to log the user activity on my api to a mongo collection. The problem is, when I add a middleware above the routes, I can log the request. But at that time the middleware have no way to know whether the request is a success or a failure. If I add the middleware below the routes it won't get called.

Now I run `res.send()` at the end of each route function. If I remove this and try to set only the status, the api get's stuck (From the front it says pending and the api does nothing). Any idea how to do this?

My app.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import filter from 'content-filter';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Raven from 'raven';

import { createFirebaseAuth } from 'express-firebase-auth';
import routes from './routes';
import { DB_CONFIG } from './config';
import firebase from './lib/firebase';
import permissions from './middleware/permissions';
import userLogs from './middleware/userLog';

// Setup environment config
dotenv.config();

// Initiate the app
const app = express();

// Connect to the database
mongoose.connect(DB_CONFIG.uri, DB_CONFIG.options);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Configure error reporting
if (process.env.RAVEN_DSN) {
  Raven.config(process.env.RAVEN_DSN).install();
  app.use(Raven.requestHandler());
}

// Apply the middleware
app.use(filter());

app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
app.use(helmet.noSniff());
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(logger('dev'));

// Add the firebase authenticatior
const firebaseAuth = createFirebaseAuth({
  firebase,
  checkEmailVerified: true,
  checkEmailVerifiedIgnoredUrls: ['/users', '/users/updatepassword']
});
app.use(firebaseAuth);

// Add the permissions module
app.use(permissions);


// Add the routes
app.use('/', routes);


// Catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// The user logs module
app.use(userLogs);

// Configure error reporting
if (process.env.RAVEN_DSN) {
  app.use(Raven.errorHandler());
}


// Error handler
app.use((err, req, res) => {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send({ error: 'Something failed!' });
});


// Setup the ip and port
app.set('port', process.env.APP_PORT || 8000);
app.set('ip', process.env.APP_IP || '127.0.0.1');

// Start the app
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  /* eslint-disable no-console */
  console.log('***************************************************************');
  console.log(`Server started on ${Date(Date.now())}`);
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${app.get('port')}`);
  console.log('***************************************************************');
});

module.exports = app;
```

The line `app.use(userLogs);` is where I attach the logs.

My routes file look like this:

```
const router = express.Router();

const routeHandler = ({ path, callback, method }) => {
  router.route(path)[method](async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      await callback(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  });
};

routeHandler({ path: '/companies', callback: createCompany, method: 'post' });

routeHandler({ path: '/companies', callback: updateCompany, method: 'put' });
```

Let's take the updateCompany function:

```
export const updateCompany = async (req, res) => {
  const companyData = req.body;

  // Get the data and update the company

  res.send({ message: 'Success!' });
};
```

UserLogs middleware:

```
const userLogs = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
  console.log('--------------------------------------------------------------------------');

};
```

Comment: Show your code. Just talking about the code you have does not give a clear picture. If we actually see it, then we can understand what you are trying to do and where you are going wrong.

Comment: Post code here without your code we could not help you

Comment: @Dipakchavda  Sorry code added!

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry code added!

Comment: So there's nothing wrong there **except** you forgot to call `next()` in the `userLogs` function. If you don't do that, then things get "stuck". Actually placing the `use(userLogs)` **after** you did your `use` for the "routes" is the **correct** thing to do. You should be able to inspect `res` and as long as you call `next()`, then you're fine.

Comment: @NeilLunn Just tried adding `next()` in `userLogs`. But still the api gets stuck.

Comment: Make sure you actually call `next()` everywhere. i.e don't just leave it inside `catch` blocks. You need to be calling it even after a `res.send()` or a `res.json()`. The only time you don't need to call `next()` is when you did not include it in the function signature at all, as in `(req, res)` opposed to `(req, res, next)`. The `next()` function is essentially the call to the "next middleware layer".

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for trying to help me! When I try to add `next()` in the routes handler right after the line `await callback(req, res, next);` **or** at the bottom of the route function (updateCompany), it gives me a 404 not found error.

Comment: Nope you aren't understanding. Your `callback` ( which would actually have to be a promise ) has `next` passed into it, so it **inside that code** that you need to be calling `next()`. So within the `createCompany` and all other functions like that, wherever they are defined.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes tried that too. `updateCompany ` is such a promise function.